# Ajuda com dats sql server e android

Tags: android, sql-server, android-layout

Tenho este código para fazer uma pesquisa ao banco SQL Server mas me dar erro:

> Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '19'

Eis o código da pesquisa:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date () );
System.out.println(currentDateandTime);


if (conn == null) {

Pesquisa = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

} else



if (conn != null) try {


Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

String queryString =  " Select SUM(DIFERENÇA)as somaMes from TOTALIZADOR WHERE  NID = 252 and DATAHORA  >= "+currentDateandTime+" and DATAHORA = "+currentDateandTime+" ";
ResultSet rs;
```

Comment: Não será do C com cedilha em DIFERENÇA?

Comment: Considerando que sua variavel currentDateandTime esteja com o conteúdo correto, escreva seu select assim:
" Select SUM(DIFERENÇA)as somaMes from TOTALIZADOR WHERE  NID = 252 and DATAHORA  >= '" +  currentDateandTime + "' and DATAHORA <= '" +  currentDateandTime + "'";

Comment: @RonaldoSantos:  Faltou delimitar o valor de data/hora entre apóstrofos, conforme sugerido pelo Reginaldo. // Mas faz sentido a comparação DATAHORA  >= X e DATAHORA <= X  ?